# Finding the kernel of Pushforward of $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^k$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

> Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb R^k$ a smooth map such that its pushforward is onto, for each $x\in U$, i.e. $$f_{*x}:T_xU\rightarrow T_{f(x)}\mathbb R^k$$ is onto , for
>   each $x\in U$. We set $M=f^{-1}(0)$. Then prove that  $$T_xM=\ker f_{*x}$$

**To prove this**, first of all, from a known theorem we see that $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $\dim M=n-k$, and it is also a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$.
Therefore, we can consider the inclusion map:

$$i:M\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$$
$$i(x^1,x^2,\dots,x^{n-k})=(x^1,x^2,\dots,x^{n-k},0,\dots,0)$$
which is an embedding.
Take the pushforward:$$i_*:TM\rightarrow T\mathbb R^n$$
Then for $x\in M$, $i_{*x}:T_xM\rightarrow T_{i(x)}\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^n$

Can you help me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the dimension of $\ker f_{*x}$? Can you show $T_x M\subset\ker f_{*x}$?

Comment: The dimension of $\ker f_{*x}$ is $n-k$ since $f_{*x}:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^k$ is onto . Also $\dim T_xM=\dim M=n-k$. So it suffices to prove that $T_xM\subset \ker f_{*x}$. Any hint for that?

Comment: Just think about how $M$ is defined!!

Comment: Take $X_x\in T_xM$. Then there exists a smooth curve $c:I\rightarrow M$ such that $c(0)=x, c'(0)=X_x$.

Then, $f_{*x}(X_x)=(f\circ c)'(0)=\dfrac{d}{dt}(f(c(t)))/_{t=0}=0$ , Because $f(c(t))\equiv0$, am I right?

(btw, what is the TeX code in order to put a vertical line $/_{t=0}$)?

Comment: Yup, you have it. You can just use $\big|_{t=0}$ [type | or \big|]