# Kernel of the pushforward of a submersion is the tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[Finding the kernel of Pushforward of $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369245/finding-the-kernel-of-pushforward-of-f-mathbb-rn-rightarrow-mathbb-rk)

I'm trying to show that $T_{p}M \subset ker(f_{*})$. We defined $T_{p}M = \{(p,m)| m \in M\}$ and $f_{*}(p,x)=(f(p),Df(p)(x))$. I've reduced the problem to showing that $Df(p)(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $M$. I can't seem to go further. How do I use the fact the f is a submersion?

EDIT: Ah, I was using an incorrect definition of the tangent space of manifold.